# JSONP and JQuery Ajax: How do I set a variable with JSONP?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, jsonp, getjson

Anyone know why my ajax fails?

I am getting the data through JSONP from here:
[JSON Data](http://www.finddata.org/buytimeseriesdata/getEncomChartSeriesData?_=1317741441988&tsId=F000008DDB)

You can use this code, and notice how the 'Alert' is never executed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://www.finddata.org/buytimeseriesdata/getEncomChartSeriesData?_=1317741441988&tsId=F000008DDB";
    $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", null, function(data) {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am getting the data through JSONP from here

No you are not getting any [JSONP data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). You are getting JSON data which is not the same notion. It seems that the url you have indicated doesn't support JSONP which is the reason why your code doesn't work. The response must be wrapped with the callback parameter you are specifying but the server ignores it.

For example if you want this to work, the [following url](http://www.finddata.org/buytimeseriesdata/getEncomChartSeriesData?_=1317741441988&tsId=F000008DDB&callback=foo) must return:

```
foo({"datas":[...],"unit":"%","records":27})
```

instead of (which it currently does):

```
{"datas":[...],"unit":"%","records":27}
```

I would recommend you reading the [following guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) if you want to perform corss domain AJAX requests.

Comment: Thanks Darin! So do I have to use a function or the other domain return something like this: `var F00000CX1E = [[Date.UTC(1979,01,31),70.74],[Date.UTC(1979,02,28),70.99]]`

Comment: @DonnyP, no, you will have to modify the `getEncomChartSeriesData` script on `http://www.finddata.org` so that it returns JSONP. There is nothing you could do if you don't have access to this remote domain. In this case your only chance is to write a server side script on your domain that will act as a bridge. Read the following guide: http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: I do have acces to the finddata.org domain. It can output whatever I need. I was hoping to use the format used [here](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js). I currently use this just inside of <script src="www.notmysite.com"></script> and it works, but I want to correctly use it with jquery and success functions.

Comment: @DonnyP, OK, if you have control here's what you need to do. Use the `callback=...` query string parameter and wrap the JSON into it as shown in my answer: `foo({"datas":[...],"unit":"%","records":27})` where `foo` is the value of the callback query string parameter passed to your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", function(data) {
[...]
```

Optional parameters in the jQuery documentatio don't need to be nulled, like in PHP.